# How do I pass an int to an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, list, listview, ienumerable, rpn

My code is giving me the following error: Compilation error (line 23, col 5): The best overloaded method match for 'Program.PrintValues(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
Compilation error (line 23, col 17): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stack opStack = new Stack();
        Stack valStack = new Stack();
        Stack postStack = new Stack();
        string infix = "A*B+C/D";
        Console.WriteLine(infix);
        char[] infixray = infix.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < infixray.Length; i++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(infixray[i]);
            if (!infixray[i].Equals("*") || !infixray[i].Equals("+") || !infixray[i].Equals("/") || !infixray[i].Equals("-"))
            {
                postStack.Push(infixray[i]);
            }
            else if (infixray[i].Equals("*") || infixray[i].Equals("+") || infixray[i].Equals("/") || infixray[i].Equals("-"))
            {
                **PrintValues(i);**
                opStack.Push(infixray[i]);
                //int multpres=1, divpres=2, addpres=3, subpres=4;
                postStack.Push(infixray[i]);
                opStack.Push(infixray[i]);
                valStack.Pop();
            //valStack.Pop();
            }

            PrintValues(postStack);
        }
    }

    public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myCollection)
    {
        foreach (Object obj in myCollection)
            Console.Write("    {0}", obj);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing `int` values to your `PrintValues` method when it expects an `IEnumerable`. Either change the signature of your `PrintValues` method to take an `int`, or pass the entire array into the method.

Comment: When you call `PrintValues(i)`, what are you expecting to happen and why?  Within that method, how are you expecting to loop over a single integer?

Comment: You can just replace it by ``Console.WriteLine(i)`` why you need to call ``PrintValues``?

Answer (score 1):

> *"How do I pass an int to an IEnumerable?"

You can create a single-item List (which implements `IEnumerable`) that contains the `int` and pass that to the method:

```
PrintValues(new List<int> { i });
```

---

Or, let's read the message the compiler is sending us:

> *"The best overloaded method match for 'Program.PrintValues(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments"*

Since the compiler is complaining about there being no suitable overload, we can provide one for it by writing an overload of the method that takes an `int` argument:

```
public static void PrintValues(int item)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", item);
}
```

(of course now the plural method name doesn't make much sense, so perhaps a new method name is also in order, like `PrintValue`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just want to output the *index* of the current branch (`if`)

Just call the `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` directly

```
...
else if (infixray[i].Equals("*") || infixray[i].Equals("+") || infixray[i].Equals("/") || infixray[i].Equals("-"))
{
     Console.WriteLine("    {i}");
     opStack.Push(infixray[i]);
```